# How to use zerolog to filter INFO logs to stdout and ERROR logs to stderr?

Tags: go, logging, zerolog

I'm using [`zerolog`](https://github.com/rs/zerolog) for *Go* logging:

```golang
zerolog.SetGlobalLevel(zerolog.InfoLevel)
log.Logger = log.Output(zerolog.ConsoleWriter{Out: os.Stderr, TimeFormat: "15:04:05"})
```

This prints all the messages into the `os.Stderr`, but I want to split the logs into multiple outputs, with the next condition:

`DebugLevel`, `InfoLevel`, and `WarnLevel` will be printed to `os.Stdout`,
and `ErrorLevel`, `FatalLevel`, and `PanicLevel` will be printed to `os.Stderr`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement [LevelWriter](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rs/zerolog#LevelWriter). For example ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/e1I7Aj6VhGf)):

```
var (
    // Using different time formats to make it clear which logger is being used
    debugOut = zerolog.ConsoleWriter{Out: os.Stdout, TimeFormat: time.RFC1123} // time format: "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"
    errorOut = zerolog.ConsoleWriter{Out: os.Stderr, TimeFormat: time.RFC3339} // time format: "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
)

// logOut implements zerolog.LevelWriter
type logOut struct{}

// Write should not be called
func (l logOut) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return os.Stdout.Write(p)
}

// WriteLevel write to the appropriate output
func (l logOut) WriteLevel(level zerolog.Level, p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if level <= zerolog.WarnLevel {
        return debugOut.Write(p)
    } else {
        return errorOut.Write(p)
    }
}

func main() {
    logger := zerolog.New(logOut{}).With().Timestamp().Logger()

    logger.Info().Str("foo", "bar").Msg("Info")   // Output: "Tue, 08 Aug 2023 22:12:31 NZST INF Info foo=bar"
    logger.Error().Str("foo", "bar").Msg("Error") // Output: "2023-08-08T22:12:31+12:00 ERR Error foo=bar"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `MultiLevelWriter`, to forward the logs into multiple `LevelWriter`s outputs (although it is not in the function signature, you should give it `LevelWriter`s, otherwise it will not do any special logic).

The `LevelWriter` is an interface with `io.Writer` and `WriteLevel(level Level, p []byte) (n int, err error)`, so you can add any `zerolog` writer you want (since it is an `io.Writer`), and use it with a level condition on `WriteLevel`.

Here is an example for a `LevelWriter`:

```golang
type SpecificLevelWriter struct {
    io.Writer
    Levels []zerolog.Level
}

func (w SpecificLevelWriter) WriteLevel(level zerolog.Level, p []byte) (int, error) {
    for _, l := range w.Levels {
        if l == level {
            return w.Write(p)
        }
    }
    return len(p), nil
}
```

Now you need to use it twice with `MultiLevelWriter`:

```golang
func CreateLogger() zerolog.Logger {
    writer := zerolog.MultiLevelWriter(
        SpecificLevelWriter{
            Writer: zerolog.ConsoleWriter{Out: os.Stdout, TimeFormat: "15:04:05"},
            Levels: []zerolog.Level{
                zerolog.DebugLevel, zerolog.InfoLevel, zerolog.WarnLevel,
            },
        },
        SpecificLevelWriter{
            Writer: zerolog.ConsoleWriter{Out: os.Stderr, TimeFormat: "15:04:05"},
            Levels: []zerolog.Level{
                zerolog.ErrorLevel, zerolog.FatalLevel, zerolog.PanicLevel,
            },
        },
    )

    return zerolog.New(writer).Logger()
}
```

Note that as I said, `zerologs` loggers are `io.Writer`, you can replace the `os.Stdout` with `zerolog.ConsoleWriter{Out: os.Stdout, TimeFormat: "15:04:05"}`